# How can I customize the command prompt when your effective gid does not match your uid?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

We frequently `sg` to switch to a "shared" effective group. I want a visible reminder that we are not using our default group. Was thinking of having the bash prompt change color or display the effective group.

Any ideas how I should do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `id -gn` to PS1: E.g: `export PS1='[\u@\h $(id -gn) \W]\$ '` can be placed in a bash profile file /etc/profile.d/set_prompt.sh.

Comment: Will it work after issuing `sg`? I don't think so.

Comment: It does. I tested my answer. You need to put it in a bash profile as `sg` starts a new shell.

Comment: Then it's cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Blatantly copying embobo's answer, you need to set up your $PROMPT_COMMAND bash variable, such as :

```
fran@orion ~ # export PROMPT_COMMAND='export PS1="[\u@\h $(id -gn) \W]\$ "'

fran@orion (20111209231004) ~ # 
fran@orion (20111209231005) ~ # 
fran@orion (20111209231006) ~ #
```

HTH

Comment: You don't need to use `$PROMPT_COMMAND` as `sg` will start a new shell .